# is it possible use Blend for Visual Studio with Uno Platform with all platforms supported?

Tags: blend, uno-platform

I have been trying to use Blend for Visual Studio with Uno Platform but it only works well with UWP. There is a trick or support for the other platforms?

Answer (score 3):

Blend itself only allows you to launch the UWP head of an Uno Platform app. At the moment Blend doesn't load Android, iOS, or WebAssembly projects.

Most of the time this should be enough. It's encouraged to use a ['Windows first dev loop'](https://platform.uno/docs/articles/concepts/overview/philosophy-of-uno.html#leverage-existing-tools) with Uno. I.e, iterate and test your app on UWP, taking advantage of faster compile times and advanced support for tools like [XAML Hot Reload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/xaml-hot-reload), and switch to iOS/Android/WASM for testing platform-specific features (and bugs).

You can edit XAML from Blend, test it on UWP, then switch to Visual Studio proper and run the same XAML on other platforms. Uno aims to match the UWP visuals pixel-for-pixel on other platforms by default. (Of course they can also be [customised per platform](https://platform.uno/docs/articles/platform-specific-xaml.html), if desired.)